# self join to fetch friend list

Tags: php, mysql

How I fetch friend list friend list from network table.

Below is the URL contain table schema and sample data.I have created following query which id-
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/646bf/5

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT m.*
FROM members AS m
  LEFT JOIN network n1
    ON (n1.mem_id = m.mem_id
        AND n1.isfriend = 'Y')
  LEFT JOIN network n2
    ON (n2.frd_id = m.mem_id
        AND n2.isfriend = 'Y')
WHERE n2.mem_id = '2' 
    AND m.profile_type='BB'  ORDER BY m.profilenam ASC
```

This query is also slow and giving duplicate result.

Please help

Comment: You need to explain your system and your problem a little better. Try including the output you would like to get from the data you have.

Comment: Can you let me know why ``network`` table joined 2 time ??

Comment: @SameerK because you can see network table schema where 2 entries are like this AB and BA including isfriend='Y'

Comment: Part of the problem is you have a LEFT JOIN for n2, but then you check the value of a column from n2 in the WHERE clause. However can you explain exactly what you want. Are you trying to find all friends of mem_id = 2 (ie, all the mem_id from network where frd_id = 2 along with all the frd_id from network where mem_id = 2)?

Answer (score 0):

Your member table has no key that us useful for that query (and index on profile_type AND profilenam would probably help). Similarly the network table has no indexes, and adding one on mem_id would help.

However can't comment on the issue with duplicate results as I don't know what your query is trying to do!

Comment: I have added all necessary index keys on all required columns